# Can we measure everything?

Tags: measurements

Can anything which can't be measured exist in the physical world? Is there anything which is present in this physical world but can't be measured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of something that is present but yet cannot be measured in practice is the future. Suppose you can measure the state of some system, then that means that there exists a Hermitian operator A that is complete (the eigenvectors span the entire Hilbert space), the reverse is also true in principle, every complete Hermitian operator corresponds to an observable quantity.

Suppose that instead of measuring A for some isolated system, we want to measure it tomorrow. Then instead of waiting till tomorrow, you can take into account the time evolution that would have occurred if you had waited until tomorrow. So, instead of A you consider the operator B defined as:

$$B = \exp\left(\frac{i H t}{\hbar}\right)A\exp\left(-\frac{i H t}{\hbar}\right)$$

If you take $t = \text{ 1 day}$, then what you are doing is evolving the system forward by 1 day applying A to it then evolving the system back in time to the present. In principle B is an observable, but in practice you cannot measure B because it will involve measuring every degree of freedom of the system in an extremely delicate way, and the smallest amount of decoherence due to interactions with the environment will completely spoil the procedure. Also, you won't be able to know how to measure it in principle without knowing the exact Hamiltonian of the system.

But this does demonstrate that in principle the future already exists in the present and someone with access to enough information could in principle measure the future. The wavefunction will then collapse in such a way that it will evolve to the measured future outcome. But in practice you won't be able to measure today who will be the next president of the US, as such a measurement would involve measuring every physical degree of freedom within a radius of about 15 light months in an extremely intricate way.

Comment: OK, I'll bite: how is "the future" currently present?  The future is by definition not here now. Or even now.  Or even**now**.  Gosh, it's hard to catch the present.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Accordiong to [eternalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternalism_(philosophy_of_time)) or the so-called "block time" you should treat the past future and present as equally real. So there is no "now" in the sense of a pointer that points out which moment is actually real, rather it's all relative, you are just as real as Alexander the Great or someone who lives in the year 3500. However, even if you reject this view and take the view that only the present is real, then the time evolution operator reveals that the future is hidden in a scrambled way in the present.

Answer (score 1):

If the world is deterministic (and even for quantum mechanics there are theories like that) then what will be measured will be, and that which we don't measure can't be just because we don't have free will to choose to measure them.

Then there is the past. We really only measure the present. But the past affects things now so it seems quite real and physical.

So those are two can't's, we can't do what we won't do and we can't affect the past and a measurement is an interaction. We can only be influenced by the past, not affect it.

Are there other things we can't measure. On general we don't bother with thibgs that can't be measured. We think of the choices we didn't make as just a valid as what we do do, so that got reality. And same with time we don't really like to treat different times as if some are more real than others.

So it seems likely that anything that exists physically but can't be measured must have some kind of symmetry to things we can measure.